# Git repository and Atom IDE: how to efficiently compare the current version of a branch with a new one on an old commit?

Tags: git, atom-editor

I have a branch (let's called it "my_fixes") in my repository that has had a number of changes throughout a long period of time. Pretty much all files had some significant changes, but now I need to branch off from it and work on a feature I previously worked on a while ago and whose changes are part of a previous commit of my "my_fixes" branch. I would like to find out what is the most efficient way to compare changes/diff between the two branches in Atom. I currently have installed GitDiff and OpenInGit package and use Git both via command line and via GitHub desktop application. I would normally revert the newly created branch to the commit of interest, add both the "my_fixes" and the new ones as Atom project and use GitDiff to move through the changes. Is that the best way? Any recommendation is more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I can't quite follow your problem or your intended fix, but it doesn't sound right. Maybe remove Atom from the equation and just ask this as a Git question. Are you saying you want to extract some particular changes from a large open branch (never a good thing) into a new feature branch? (ie. cherry pick)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are extraordinarily few cases in which you should have a long-running development branch (and for someone that needs to ask this question, I would go as far as to say none).

It sounds like what you're saying is that you have two branches, `<old-feature>` and `<my-fixes>`, and changes that you committed in `<old-feature>` were rebased/cherry-picked or manually applied in `<my-fixes>` many commits ago, and now you're seeking to figure out how to diff the two branches in such a way that you can easily figure out what changes you need to analyze.

The solution I think you're looking for is

```
git diff --stat <old-feature> <my-fixes>
```

which will give you the list of files that have changed, and then

```
git diff <old-feature> <my-fixes> -- <fileA> <fileB> ... <fileZ>
```

which will show you the difference between files `<fileA> <fileB> ... <fileZ>` between `<old-feature>` and `<my-fixes>`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a big fan of Github if you can use that. Just push it and compare the two branches over it, [like in Rails](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/4-2-8...4-2-stable).